# Python import torch takes a long time to init

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, torch

I've built a system to train neural networks in Python 3.7 using pytorch and when it is ready to start, I run it on an AWS EC2 from an AMI image that is setup to run the training. When I launch a new EC2 instance and run my script it takes a long time > 5 minutes to `import torch` I've even gone so far as to just start the instance and open a python3 shell and just run `import torch` and the same thing happens. It is only the first time that I run it that it takes this long. Subsequent runs are fine.

If I press ctrl-c I get

```
File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 190, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
RuntimeError: KeyboardInterrupt:
```

When interrupting it, the next time I try it will still take a while to finish.

The EC2 instance is idle while this is happening and there is nothing of note showing in `htop`

What is causing this to take so long to initialize? Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

Python: 3.7
Torch: 1.7.1+cu110
OS: Amazon Linux 2

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't think it is specific to EC2 instances, because I am not using AWS. This issue is absurd.

Comment: I'm having the same problem too. It takes around 30 seconds on my AWS equivalent, and less than a ms locally.

Answer (score -4):

From [cloudonaut's "EBS Snapshot Pitfalls"](https://cloudonaut.io/ebs-snapshot-pitfalls/):

> Restoring a volume based on an EBS snapshot typically takes a few seconds only. However, the data is not available from the beginning. Instead, EBS restores the data asynchronously. You will notice high latencies during that period.

Consider using AWS's Fast Snapshot feature for ~$500/month, or see alternatives like those described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1002937/aws-fast-snapshot-restore-cost-and-restore-time).